# Basic question about ASP.NET mechanism

Tags: asp.net, events

How events relationship between functions occur ?

For example:

When we click submit button how CLR or IIS determine which function has to work ?

I know how can relate functions with events but I dont know how background mechanism work.I don't know Is there reflection or another else.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET has the concept of the Page Life Cycle. This is an ordered sent of events which are triggered. One important interface in this mechanism is the [IPostbackEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackeventhandler.aspx) interface.

Update due to comment:
The automatic eventing mechanism is turned on due to the [AutoEventWireup="true"](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814745) in the page directive.

Grz, Kris.

Comment: In Winforms VS automaticly relate functions by addin them into events but in WEB page, I still couln't understand it even from links.I haven't seen any code  use compenents event which is created by VS.

Answer (score 1):

Through delegates